# Iterating and enumerating an array, not getting same results

Tags: javascript, iteration, enumeration

I have to pass a test on this line of code and after reading various posts about making sure that I am iterating an array and not enumerating to try and avoid possible complications with prototype chaining etc. (to be honest I don't understand *everything* however I am getting there).

I have two pieces of code that appear to be doing the same thing, just one is enumerating and one is iterating. However, the part that has me pulling my hair out is that if I enumerate then I pass all the tests but if I iterate then I don't, I fail the part that says "should copy properties from source to destination"

Here is the iteration:

```
function copy(destination, source){
var index;
for (index = 0; index <= source.length; index++) {
  if (source.propertyIsEnumerable(index) && destination[index] === undefined) {
    destination[index] = source[index];
  }
}
return destination;
```

I am passing the second argument in a function called "source" to the first function called "destination".

now when I put the enumeration code in I pass all tests:

```
function copy(destination, source){
var index;
for (var index in source) {
  if (source.propertyIsEnumerable(index) && destination[index] === undefined)
    destination[index] = source[index];
}
return destination;
};
```

Now I believe they are doing the same thing however it would appear that they aren't?

Comment: What does the test look like? What does `destination` look like for both snippets?

Comment: please add the content of the variables as well.

Comment: You left out the most important thing out of your question: the actual object you are iterating over. Show us how it is defined, and show use the result of the iteration in both cases. Now I suppose destination is an array, in that case you should not use for in at first place, because it enumerates enumerable properties. If destination is an object, then you should use Object.keys, not for in either.

Comment: The iteration version ignores named properties of the array, it only copies indexed elements.

Answer (score 0):

The iteration version fails on an example like this. Both versions copy the indexed elements, but only the enumeration version copies named properties of the array object.

```js
var oldArray = [1, 2, , 4];
oldArray.someProp = "foo";

var newArray1 = copyArrayIter(oldArray);
console.log(newArray1);
console.log(newArray1.someProp);

var newArray2 = copyArrayEnum(oldArray);
console.log(newArray2);
console.log(newArray2.someProp);

function copyArrayIter(source) {
  var index;
  var destination = [];
  for (index = 0; index <= source.length; index++) {
    if (source.propertyIsEnumerable(index) && destination[index] === undefined) {
      destination[index] = source[index];
    }
  }
  return destination;
}

function copyArrayEnum(source) {
  var index;
  var destination = [];
  for (var index in source) {
    if (source.propertyIsEnumerable(index) && destination[index] === undefined)
      destination[index] = source[index];
  }
  return destination;
};
```

It will copy the elements at indexes `0`, `1`, and `3`, but it won't copy the `someProp` property.